# Not able to locate the text field inside the iframe using protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, iframe, protractor, end-to-end

```
<iframe class="embedded-tax-form" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="http://forms.tax-api-1w7xi0.addevcloudsites.myob.com/au-fbt-2015/1.0.0/?host=addevcloudsites.myob.com&amp;client=deb4bb44-994f-4ce7-aea8-6507925beb8a" id="iFrameResizer1" style="overflow: hidden; height: 3971px;"></iframe>
<input id="input.ReportingParty.Identifiers.TaxFileNumber.Identifier" type="text" ng-model="form.fields['ReportingParty.Identifiers.TaxFileNumber.Identifier'].value" ng-change="run()" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-readonly="form.fields['ReportingParty.Identifiers.TaxFileNumber.Identifier'].source === 'calculation'" source-selection="ReportingParty.Identifiers.TaxFileNumber.Identifier">
```

I have text field embedded inside the Iframe and I'm using the Protractor and written the code as below, as the latest protract we need not have to instantiate the instance:

```
it('should show the functioning input directive example', function () {
      browser.get('http://qa5.addevcloudsites.myob.com/tax/edit/?client=4cccbc62-15b1-41e3-a9ed-0d93e7d05db2');
      // Ensure that the page is loaded before trying to switch frames.
      browser.waitForAngular();
      browser.switchTo().frame('embedded-tax-form');
      var nameInput = element(by.model("form.fields['ReportingParty.Identifiers.TaxFileNumber.Identifier'].value"));
      nameInput.sendKeys('222);
    });
```

when I run this, complete page gets refreshed and says

> ReferenceError: iframe is not defined NoSuchFrameError: no such frame

I checked whether element is present writing on console and used elementory:

```
 elementArrayFinder_:    { getWebElements: [Function],
     actionResults_: undefined,
     locator_: { using: 'css selector', value: '.embedded-tax-form' },
     click: [Function],
```

Let me know, how I should handle in protractor latest. Please let me know if you  need any more information on this.

Comment: Please improve formatting of your question: format code as code, text as text...

Answer (score 0):

browser.switchTo().frame('iFrameResizer1').
Since this needs and ID and you are giving the class-name!

Hope this works!

Comment: var iframe =   browser.switchTo().frame('iFrameResizer0')
                var nameInput = element(by.model('"form.fields[\'ReportingParty.Identifiers.TaxFileNumber.Identifier\'].value"'));
                nameInput.sendKeys('222'); still get the error as ==== async task ==== WebDriver.switchTo().frame(iFrameResizer0) at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (c:\Users\plingala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\sele‌​nium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\ ==== async task ====Asynchronous test function: it() at [object Object].<anonymous>

Comment: The same frame is getting identified by webdriverIO, I cant us this as aour page is ANgular page. I cant use webdriverjs-angular as my log in is using Non angular. So I want the took tht support both angular and non angular page automation